# Node, Mongoose - $or operator not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Within my express app, I have a mongoose schema like so:

User model schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      minlength: 4,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 255,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
    },
})
```

Here is an operation I do in one of my endpoints. I expect a  user to be returned if `req.body.usernameOrEmail` matches a `username` or `email` of a `User`. Here is the operation:

```
let user = await User.find({ $or: [ { username: req.body.usernameOrEmail }, { email: req.body.usernameOrEmail } ] })
if (!user) return res.send('No user found')
```

What happens is that if I put anything `req.body.usernameOrEmail`, the `'No user found'` message is **not** printed as expected. Anybody know whats going wrong with the operation performed above? Thanks.

Comment: @mickl  Hello. The result is expected. The value I assign to `req.body.usernameOrEmail` is printed when I do this.

Answer (score 3):

awaited `.find()` method returns an empty array which is **truthy** in JavaScript, try:

```js
console.log(![])
```

You can use `.findOne()` instead and in that case `null` will be returned when there's no match and your condition will work